# If the Isthmus between North & South America did not exist what would happen to the Gulfstream and thus the weather in Western Europe?

Tags: weather-forecasting

Given the differences in temperature, salinity and elevation between the Pacific & Atlantic oceans, what would happen to the Gulf Stream and thus the weather in western Europe and also the eastern seaboard of North America if the isthmus between North and South America were to no longer exist, for whatever reason?

Comment: @trondhansen I think a strong flow into the Atlantic would happen, probably elevanting its level a lot. Maybe even with 10m. Furthermore, the objective data about the *real* elevation of the level of the Oceans does not support your comments.

Comment: @trondhansen Missing key information: The question is not about the destruction of Panama country, but about the destruction of the Panama canal. The height difference between the levels of the Atlantic and the Pacific is about 10m.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica i did misunderstand your comment,but it does not change the fact that it is too little water to make any significant changes in the weather on the other side of the atlantic ocean the difference of the water level in the atlantic vs pacific ocean is 20 cm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panama_Canal#Water_issues

Comment: @trondhansen [My source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0146631361900442) says 17-40cm, but it is still much more small than I knew before. This information could be qualified as an useful answer, making the question on-topic (probably after some edit).

Comment: The general idea of this question is fine but it needs to have extraneous items such as nukes & the Panama Canal removed. Firstly, there are differences between the Pacific & Atlantic oceans: temperature, salinity & elevation. There are even differences between the northern & southern parts of each ocean. The isthmus of between North & South America blocks the two oceans from interacting with each other. I think the question should be: *If the isthmus between North & South America didn't exist, for whatever reason,  what would happen to the Gulf Stream & the weather in Europe?* ...

Comment: ... [*On the temperature, salinity, and density differences between the Atlantic and Pacific oceans in the upper kilometre*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0146631361900442) and [*Atlantic and Pacific Ocean DO NOT MIX*](http://www.geologypage.com/2017/11/atlantic-pacific-ocean-not-mix.html)

Comment: Suggesting to further refine the question in the direction "how did climate in Europe change during the time the isthmus closed, and can part of the change be attributed to the closing". If OP and the community consent ofc. the discussion is pretty complex: https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/8/e1600883.full and comments: https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/3/6/e1602321.full and https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/3/6/e1602320.full, and https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-37790-2, so we're possibly though most of Neogene, here.

Comment: the question have been changed in a way that it now is on topic here,i have removed my comments they are no longer relevant  to this question.

Comment: it might be a good idea to clean up the comments  but to keep the sources as they contain relevant information to build an answer on.